# Trello API: Show date on which a card's label was applied

Tags: api, trello

Using the [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/), is there a way to get the date & time on which a label was appended to a card?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since posting, I actually found an call that does give the date & time of last activity (which  includes label was added / changed):

`https://api.trello.com/1/cards/BOARD_ID?fields=name&fields=dateLastActivity&key=APPLICATION_KEY&token=MEMBER_TOKEN`

Comment: Did I get downvoted because I answered my own question? I'm pretty new to SO so would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I think it's rather because last activity does not mean it's the date when label has been added, it may be any action

Answer (score 0):

No, the API does not currently expose that information.  It does exist, so it is possible that it will be exposed in the future.